# Is it Necessary to Store Transactions processed by a Payment Gateway?

Tags: database-design, e-commerce

**The background:** I am designing a website to host some services online. To use any service, a customer is required to pay a fee using a credit card. The transaction is being processed by the payment gateway, which keeps a record of the amount collected, the card holder name, the last four digits of the credit card number and the transaction date. If a success response is returned, a code will be run to update the customer database to enable the customer to use the paid service. Else, the customer will be redirected to a failed transaction page.

**The question:** As this is the first time I am designing an e-commerce application, I would like to get some advice. My question is whether there is any need to store what will be stored in the payment gateway separately on a `transaction` table, prior to transmitting the data to the gateway as a form of verification or for accounting purposes. It would be great to hear from those who have actual experience on designing e-commerce application. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your not referring to storing (or even having access to) card data (number/cvv etc) which is a completely different kettle of fish, I would suggest you store whatever you can whenever you can;

- Its a tiny amount of data that's trivial, cheap & easy to store
- Being able to trace every detail of a transaction for auditing/customer enquiries etc. solely on your own system is surely better than having to depend on someone else
- You can do whatever you like with it in terms of analysis/reporting without being dependent on services provided by the 3rd party gateway
- What if the gateway provider went bust?
- If you decide to change gateways or implement additional gateways you will be able to maintain a central store of normalized transaction data

Comment: This is a good answer. I can see the rationale behind now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I would log customer name, transaction date and time, transaction amount, payment gateway response but NOT any details of the cc, you don't need it so don't hold it. This would allow you to analyse usage of the website, spot possible problems with the gateway etc. Assuming the gateway returns some form of transaction id you might want to hold that as well.

Comment: I can have the option of logging before transmission and after. To get the transaction response, I can only do it after only. Any requirement to do it before data transmission? Is there any use for accounting purpose?

Answer (score 0):

I for one haven't worked with e-commerce, but I've worked for a very big bank once, and their usual policy was to always keep audit tables with data concerning every important transaction that takes place in the system.

I believe that this is important because you will always have a "rollback" option if you discover a bug in your system later on, and most importantly if someone from inside your company is trying to fraud or take advantage of your system, it will be easier to catch them if you have audit tables (I know this sounds paranoid, but banks are always paranoid about security).

Finally since you are dealing with other people's money, I think that you should keep track of your transactions, at least for a while. You could create a trigger that erases transactions that are more than one or two years old for example.

Comment: I can always login to the payment gateway website to view the transaction record. I am not sure whether I should create a copy from there or create a process to log the transaction prior to sending over to the payment gateway. Regarding rollback, I don't see how it should occur for my application since there is no transfer of funds.